# calling web service from html

Tags: java, javascript, html

We have created web service for temperature conversion using Netbeans. It is working fine.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "tempConverter")
public Double tempConverter(@WebParam(name = "temp") double temp, 
                            @WebParam(name = "choice") int choice) {
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
        tempConv =  (9.0/5.0)*(ip)+32.0;
        break;

        case 2:
        tempConv = (5.0/9.0)*(ip-32.0);
        break;
     }
     return tempConv;
}
```

But We want to use this web service in html. chanService is the name of webservice.

Code for that is:

```
<script language="javascript">
            function initialize()
            {
                service.useService("http://localhost:8080/chanService/chanService.java?WSDL","tempConverterService");
            }

            function getTemp()
            {
                var temp,choice;
                temp=document.getElementById('temp').value;
                choice=document.getElementById('choice').value;
                service.tempConverterService.callService(tempConverter,temp,choice);

            }
            function Result() 
{ 
alert(event.result.value); 
} 


        </script>

    </head> 
    <body onload="initialize()" id="service" onresult="Result()">
        <form name="form1">
            <input type="text" name="temp" id="temp" value="0" size="50" />
            <input type="text" name="choice" value="1" id="choice" size="50" />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" onclick="getTemp()"/>
        </form>
```

But this isnt working. Please help,

Comment: are you using a specific java library (to get the 'service' object)?

Comment: @RyanFernandes you meant `javascript`, not `java` library?

Comment: yup sorry.. javascript library

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in Firebug/Web Inspector to see the requests going around?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style="behavior:url(webservice.htc)" in the body tag and place the file in the same folder of your page.

See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531063(v=vs.85).aspx